# How come that $N \subset H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question on one of my abstract algebra exams that goes like this:

Given a group $G$ with a subgroup $H$, with finite index $[G :H]$, also given is $N \subset G$.
With $N = \bigcap_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}$.

Show that $N \subset H$

There are more questions regarding this exercise, but I need to understand this first before I can go further. I have trouble understanding how this comes about.

Comment: Isn't $eHe^{-1} = H$?

Comment: Use $g=1$ in the definition of $N$, along with the fact that you are taking intersections.

Comment: @Pimziengs I think you want $N \le H$.

Comment: Yes, $eHe^{-1} = H$. But I dont know how to exactly use that.

Comment: @Pimziengs Are you trying to show that $N$ is a *subset* of $H$ or a *subgroup* of $H$?

Comment: Subset of $H$, further on I have to show that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ and a normal subgroup of $G$. But I first need to understand this bit.

Comment: @Pimziengs Okay, so $A \cap B \subseteq A$. Use that with the above.

Comment: Thanks, your the best! Now I see it!